# How to add svg-icons from material-ui

Tags: material-ui

There are a ton of icons in material-ui/lib/svg-icons.

import statements fail for almost all of them.

example:

```
import NavigationClose = require('material-ui/src/svg-icons/navigation/close'); // fails
```

How to get access to these icons in .jsx code?

Answer (score 2):

1. You are doomed to fail when mixing `import` with `require()`.
2. You should use `lib/` instead of `src/`.

```js
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/close';
// OR
const NavigationClose = require('material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/close');
```

Comment: True, plus the definition for NavigationClose was missing from the material-ui.d.ts file. Once I created a def (following the pattern of NavigationMenu), all was fine.